# Algorithm: 2 sets A and B form sum set C. A and C are given find B

Tags: java, algorithm, linear-search

2 sets A and B form a sum set C, which means S(A,B) = {a+b where a belongs A, b belongs to B}
we are given C and A we need to find B.
[see here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/linear-search/practice-problems/algorithm/easy-sum-set-problem-7e6841ca/)

so i took the approach of ai - cj = m element, if m element is found in all iterations of ai then add to B

This is better explained over here

Input
a = {1 2}
x = {3 4 5}
Output
Minus Value a=1 c=3 match 2 and the match value 2
Minus Value  a=2 c=4 match 2 and the match value 2
match value 2
Minus Value a=1 c=4 match 3 and the match value 3
Minus Value a=2 c=5 match 3 and the match value 3
match value 3
Minus Value a=1 c=5 match 4 and the match value 4

result = 2,3 which is correct

But for some of the test cases its failing

like

```
8 12 15 18 24 30 33 40 41 48

3 5 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 94 97
```

this test case is failing. The expected output is

1 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 46 49

and my output is

1 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 45 46 49

`45` this is the extra element

code:

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    int m = sc.nextInt();
    int[] c= new int[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        c[i] = sc.nextInt();
    
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(c);
    int b[] = new int[m];
    int k=0;
    int v = 0;
    while(v!=c.length)
    {
        int flag=0;
        int match = (a[0]>c[v])? a[0]-c[v] : c[v]-a[0]; //since a[0] is the first iteration all of the common elements must be present here
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++) 
        {
            flag=0;
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                int minus = (a[i]>c[j])? a[i]-c[j] : c[j]-a[i];
               
                if(minus == match){
                   //  System.out.println("Minus Value initial a "+a[i]+" c "+c[j]+" match "+ minus+ " and the match value "+ match);
                    flag = 1;
                    break;}
            }
            if(flag==0)
                break;
        }
        if(flag==1){
         //   System.out.println("match value "+ match);
        b[k++] = match;
            }
        v++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        System.out.print(b[i]+" ");

    }
}
```

please take a look and let me know whats wrong with my algorithm or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

So,first thing sorting would not add much value as you are anyways using 2 nested for loops.

Next up, a is a positive array. a[i] - c[i] does not make sense as c[i] would always be greater than a[i].

You are saying you need to add it in the answer only if it is found in all iterations.

But, I dont think your code does that.

Your basic idea is correct.

If a + b =c -> b = (a-c)

So, here's how I would solve this. Same idea but maintaining a map.

Now, thing you need to do here is maintain a map of all difference counts between c and a.

If this count matches a's length then you got the match, output it.

A simple code for this would be:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

for(int v: c){
   for(int u: a){
      int diff = v-u;
      map.put(diff,map.getOrDefault(diff,0)+1);
   }
}

        
for(int i: map.keySet()){
   if(map.get(i)==a.length){
      System.out.print(i+" ");
   }
}
```